# Create a model object using the json where all keys are not model's fields

Tags: python, django, database, django-models, django-orm

I have a model as below:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = model.CharField(max_length = 255)
    mobile = model.IntegerField(null = True)
    city = model.CharField(max_length = 255)
```

Now i need to create a model object using a json as below:

```
data = { "name" : "John", 
        "age" : 31, 
        "city" : "New York", 
        "mobile" : 1234432156,
        "address" : "xyz" }
```

In the above json, `name`, `mobile`, `city` are the fields in `Person` model. I have to create a model object using the above json. I have done like this:

```
Person.objects.create(**data)
```

But it is throwing an error saying `'age' is invalid keyword argument for this function`. My understanding is that, it is throwing error since there is no age field in the model.

How to create the model instance with such a json where all the keys are not the fields in the model.

Comment: But what are you expecting to happen with the age value? Why are you including it at all?

Comment: Thanks for your response. This is a sample question representing my problem. That json is not created by any one, it is generated from data base queries. In contrast, `age` might be not be used here, but it can be used in some other place.

Comment: This is not JSON, this is a Python dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you know that your data is the same "shape" (i.e. has the same fields) as your model, you're going to be better off writing this out explicitly:

```
Person.objects.create(name=data['name'], mobile=data['mobile'], city=data['city'])
```

(This is one of those [explicit is better than implicit](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) moments.)

Comment: thanks for your reply. I have done the same thing. I have written a function inside model and passed the data to that function. The function does the same thing you have done inside create